# Make Chrome and Firefox display a viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, viewport

I may just be missing something but neither this meta tag:

```
<meta id="gameViewport" name="viewport" content="width:device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimal-ui, target-densityDpi=device-dpi">
```

nor these css3 directives:

```
@-webkit-viewport {
    height: 704px;
    width: 1280px;
}
@-viewport {
    height: 704px; 
    width: 1280px;
}
@viewport {
    height: 704px; 
    width: 1280px;
}
```

seem to be making any difference at all, chrome and ff don't responsively change the viewport.  Is there another way I should be doing this?  For ie I was able to use the very simple:

```
@-ms-viewport {
    height: 704px;
    width: 1280px;
}
```

css3 directive to get what I wanted but apparently that is not supported on other browsers?  Am I doing something wrong with what I have or is there a better way to achieve the same thing in ie in other browsers?  The site I'm working on is hosted here: [damiankulp.com/damian/gallery/protobox](http://damiankulp.com/damian/gallery/protobox)

Comment: FF at least doesn't do `@viewport` at all. There's an entry in MDN's [table of contents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference), but it doesn't point to an existing page. That probably means `@viewport` won't come to Mozilla any time soon. And if it does, it will probably be called `@-moz-viewport` at first.

Comment: If the worst comes to the worst, you can always do `html{width:704px; height:1280px}` of course.

Comment: I was trying to use viewports to make stuff responsive...  And the FF thing sucks, is there another way to do something similar?

Comment: I could say media queries, but that would only make you throw your hands up in frustration.

Comment: hm, well then.  So the answer is: "no, there really isn't any way to make Chrome or FF responsively size the content to fit the screen regardless of resolution"?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but `content="width=device-width, ..."` instead of `content="width:device-width, ..."` may help.

Comment: I wish, Chrome still doesn't resize and neither does ff.